# Is there a way to restore deleted chrome cache files?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache, undelete

Suppose the cache files have been deleted by pressing shift+ctrl+delete on chrome. the files starting with f_* are removed and the data_* files data_0, data_1... are reduced. So we can not use chrome cache viewer because the files are away. I tried with commercial and free undelete softwares (easeus, recuva, puran, activeundelete) they find the deleted f_ and data_ files but when i recover them and use with nirsoft google chrome cace viewer, i see corrupted results. I need both the urls and the files in the cache before delete operation. Is there any other way? DNS cache is not an option, computer has been reset. google my activity will not help because it only contains the visited urls (history), but the external urls visitied by the first url.

Comment: i recovered data_1, data_2 and data_3 but data_0 is lost. and google cache viewer needs the data_0. Is there a way to parse or fetch some info from the currently data files?

Answer (score 1):

@benchpresser : -"yes you still have an opportunity get your cache files back. i did this before"(As you said chance of getting the files currupted is more but still if you use power data recocvery its the best option to find files with small size..dont use easeUS in this case then..and still you having the chance of getting the uincode of files you lost you can have a try in that way too.)
Requirements
1.Data recovery tool (Power-data recovery, EaseUS Data Recovery etc)
2.OS:- Windows

> Step 1. Select the disk storage location where you want to recover from Google Chrome cache files and click "Scan".
>
> Step 2.Data Recovery  will start a scan first. After the scan completes, a deep scan will automatically launch in order to find more files.
>
> Step 3. Choose the file(s) you want to recover by file types from the scanning results. Click "Recover" button to recover the selected files. Here you should save all the recovered files on a different drive or memory card in case of data recovery failure.

i hope this will help

Comment: Thanks, i will try power data. I already tried easeus but the recovered files were corrupted. I tried to view the files with EmEditor, the fetch some uncorrupted data, but nothing was meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore cleared cache, history or cookies if DNS cache has been cleared. Unfortunately, I believe you are out of luck.